# 401 USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED on login attempt

Tags: docusignapi

Our application allows customers to log in to their own DocuSign account for sending envelopes.

We use this API endpoint:

https://www.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information

And an X-Docusign-Authentication header like this, where "XXX-XXXXX-XXXX" is our application's integrator key:

`<DocuSignCredentials><Username>their@email.address</Username><Password>password111</Password><IntegratorKey>XXX-XXXXX-XXXX</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>`

one of our customers is logging into the application and receives this error:

USER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED : One or both of Username and Password are invalid

However, the username / password are correct (verified by logging in manually at https://www.docusign.net).

Our customer was told that they can't use our application / integration without an API plan:

https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing/api-plans-b

Is this accurate? Would they be required to have an API plan even though they are logging in through our application / integration key?

They have a Business Plus plan today.

Answer (score 0):

Business plan includes API access, so that's not the issue. (And who told them differently?)

Does the customer's password contain any characters not allowed in XML?

Try changing to a simpler password for testing purposes. If still an issue, then I suggest that you contact DocuSign customer support and ask for the Partner developer support team.